# Issue executing shell file on Mac OS

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm new to Mac OS, I have a `.sh` file that contains a few instructions to startup Laravel server, React Native Metro server, ngrok etc.

When I execute with :

```
bash /Users/username/Desktop/proyectos/wooloveapp.com/laravelapp/scripts/app-startup-mac.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan db:drop && php artisan db:create && php artisan migrate --seed does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/ngrok http 8000 does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/woo && cd android  && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan websockets:serve does not exist.
```

**My script is simple, the locations are exact, for each line I want to open a terminal and execute the following actions on that same terminal**, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve"

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan db:drop && php artisan db:create && php artisan migrate --seed"

open -a Terminal "ngrok http 8000"

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/woo && cd android  && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache"

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan websockets:serve"
```

Comment: You can't do `open -a Terminal "shell command to run"`, but there probably is no need for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to open five Terminals (which won't work because Terminal assumes whatever you pass as an argument is a file), you can put all the commands directly into your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan db:drop && php artisan db:create && php artisan migrate --seed
ngrok http 8000
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/woo/android && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan websockets:serve
```

If any of the `php`, `ngrok`or `npx` calls are blocking, add a `&` at the end of the command to run it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the `open` man page:

```
NAME
     open – open files and directories

SYNOPSIS
     open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-F] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-j] [-h] [-u URL] [-s sdk]
          [-b bundle_identifier] [-a application] [--env VAR] [--stderr PATH] [--stdin PATH]
          [--stdout PATH] file ... [--args arg1 ...]
DESCRIPTION
     The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked
     the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the default application as
     determined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files.
```

"cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve" is not a filename.