# Trying to execute shell commands opening multiple terminals

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, bash, php

I have a shell command which I use to setup multiple servers (metro, laravel, ngrok). Each of these processes needs to be executed in its own Terminal window. The issue right now is that all I'm able to do is start the laravel server and the command hangs there...

Is it possible to execute each line of the command in their corresponding Terminal window?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan db:drop && php artisan db:create && php artisan migrate --seed
ngrok http 8000
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/woo/android && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan websockets:serve
```

Comment: Why does each server need their own terminal?  What problem are you trying to overcome?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461100/issue-executing-shell-file-on-mac-os is related. As mentioned there, you need to add `&` if one of the commands doesn't return.

Comment: But as Allan asked: Is there a need to have each command run in its own window, e.g. do you want to see specific log output? Or do you just want to work around any "run in the background" issues?

Comment: Yeas, each has to run in a Terminal, this is pretty easy to do on Windows

Comment: where should I put the & ? I added it at the end but nothing: sh mycommand.sh & @nohillside

Comment: While macOS ≠ Windows, there’s no obvious reason to have different processes running in Terminal windows in either OS.  Unless there’s something specific (which you haven’t articulated as of yet), just run them and push them to the background.  The downside to running anything in a a Terminal is that when you close it, you kill the process unless you use `nohup`

Comment: A & at the very end of each line should be enough.

Comment: Aren't you essentially asking how to start a terminal window from the command line? Most terminal programs have an option to have a command being executed on startup. Of course this option depends on the terminal program you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it can be done using the OP's requirement that "each of these processes needs to be executed in its own Terminal window".

Based on the question [Applescript to open a NEW terminal window in current space](https://superuser.com/questions/195633/applescript-to-open-a-new-terminal-window-in-current-space), the following function could be defined in the OP's script.

```
doscript() { 
    set "${1//\\/\\\\}" # This command replaces each \ with \\
    set "${1//\"/\\\"}" # This command replaces each " with \"
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e "do script \"$1\"" -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'
}
```

In the case of the OP's question, the two `set` commands in the `doscript` function are probably not required.

For example, the following command

```
cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve
```

would be replaced by the following

```
doscript 'cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve'
```

command.